# for loop slow performance for large data

Tags: c#, for-loop, devexpress

i'm using devexpress controls.  Below code is used in selectionChanged event. This for loop results in slow performance when data is huge. Is there a way we can optimize this one?

```
         for (int i = 0; i < gridView.RowCount; i++)
         {
            int currentHandle = gridView.GetVisibleRowHandle(i);
            var row = gridView.GetRow(currentHandle) as xxxx;

            if (gridView.IsRowSelected(currentHandle) && !listSelectedItems.Contains(row))
            {
              listSelectedItems.Add(row);
            }
            else if (!gridView.IsRowSelected(currentHandle) && listSelectedItems.Contains(row))
            {
              listSelectedItems.Remove(row);
            }
         }

         gridControl2.Datasource = listSelectedItems;
         //sometimes refresh datasource is also slow and I tried using beginupdate and endupdate but they never helped
         gridControl2.RefreshDatasource();
```

Comment: Maybe assign the return of `listSelectedItems.Contains()` to a bool, you are checking it twice in the same function which means it will go through the entire collection twice

Comment: The `Remove()` call could be expensive if it gets called a lot.  If you don't need the selected items collection to be in order, you could use a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

For `gridControl2` use `BindingList`. With `BindingList` there are no need to refresh your `gridControl2` every time.

```
private BindingList<SomeClass> _selected;
```

```
gridControl2.DataSource = _selected;
```

In `SelectionChanged` event use `SelectionChangedEventArgs` object and its `SelectionChangedEventArgs.Action` member. And use `GridView.GetSelectedRows()` method to obtains the all selected rows in view.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Data.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case CollectionChangeAction.Add:
            var addedRow = (SomeClass)gridView1.GetRow(e.ControllerRow);

            if (!_selected.Contains(addedRow)) //You need this check only when gridView1.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode == GridMultiSelectMode.CellSelect
                _selected.Add(addedRow);
            break;
        case CollectionChangeAction.Remove:
            _selected.Remove((SomeClass)gridView1.GetRow(e.ControllerRow));
            break;
        case CollectionChangeAction.Refresh:

            gridView2.BeginDataUpdate();

            _selected.Clear();

            var rows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows().Select(row => (SomeClass)gridView1.GetRow(row));
            foreach (var row in rows)
                _selected.Add(row);

            gridView2.EndDataUpdate();

            break;
    }
}
```